# Laravel Notification Channel

Tags: laravel, notifications, sms

I am getting this error, what should i do?
Can't really find what I miss.

Undefined function App\Console\Commands\Notify

Here is the command:

```
    public function handle()
    {
        $user = DB::table('users')
        ->whereIn('role',['athlete'])
        ->andWhere('contact_number');
        $user = notify(new SendSMS);
    }
}
```

The notification:

```
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return [TwilioChannel::class];
    }

    public function toTwilio($notifiable)
    {
        return (new TwilioSmsMessage())
            ->content("Hi {$notifiable->first_name}. Your account was approved!");
    }
}
```

Thank you!!

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/notifications#using-the-notifiable-trait

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`notify` is a method of the `Notifiable` trait, also you cant call notify from the DB query you should use your Eloquent Model, also
you need to add `Notifiable` to your `User` model

Example :

```
$user = User::whereIn('role',['athlete'])
    ->where('contact_number', 'some value')
    ->get();
$user->each->notify(new SendSMS());
```

I hope it's helpful